# NOT on array Place

Tags: c

I'm having this:

```
char board_game [3][3] = {0}; // The Board Game
```

And after this I'm doing that:

```
scanf("%d%d", &row, &col); // Get The Input And Put It In Row And Column
printf("%d",board_game[row][col]);
```

There is some output that I don't understand and what does that line mean `board_game[row][col]`?

```
|    input    | output
| row  | col  |
|______|______|________
|   0  |   0  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   0  |   1  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   0  |   2  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   0  |   3  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   1  |   0  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   1  |   1  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   1  |   2  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   1  |   3  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   2  |   0  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   2  |   1  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   2  |   2  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   2  |   3  |   1     **WHY 1?**
|------|------|--------
|   3  |   0  |   1     **WHY 1?**
|------|------|--------
|   3  |   1  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   3  |   2  |   0
|------|------|--------
|   3  |   3  |   0
|------|------|--------
```

Can you please explain to me what is going on?

Comment: It's out-of-bounds.

Comment: the source code is incomplete.

Comment: The declaration `[3]` means that the indices 0 ... 2 are valid. 3 is not, therefore undefined behaviour. => if you needed index `3` to be valid, you must declare `char board_game[4][4]  = {0}`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so why where 3 3 is 0

Comment: If you don't understand what `board_game[row][col]` means, then perhaps you should [get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over by reading them?

Comment: If you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) then *anything* could happen. In reality, what's happening is that you attempt to read memory that doesn't belong to you, and just read its contents. It might work, or it might crash.

Comment: It's the value in that offsets, I know, but why it's 0 and 1 in Other Places

Comment: If you use a recent `gcc`, compile with `-fsanitize=undefined` and then run your program.

Comment: Lastly, C doesn't have any kind of bounds checking. It's up to you to make sure the code doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: @Programmmer_Z it is 0 or 1 or anything, because the behaviour of your program is **undefined**. A butterfly flaps its wings - what will happen?

Comment: Don't _explain_ what your code does, but **show** a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Out Of Bound and undefined (offsets: 3, 3| 3, 0) when the indexes only can be between 0..2

And you declared 0 at the start to all the array values

`board_game[row][col]` Means the value of the array in that offsets

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a memory location that doesnot belong to your array. When you define an array of size 3 the index are 0,1,2 . The values board game[0][3],board game[1][3],board game[2][3],board game[3][0],board game[3][1], board game[3][2],board game[3][3] are out of bound